# Argument requirement dependence on type with default value [Class generic]

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to create generic class, which has compare function, such that takes as an arguments only the provided type (`number` by default):

```
class Foo<T = number> {
    
    isGreater: (v1: T, v2: T) => boolean   

    constructor()
    constructor(isGreater: (v1: T, v2: T) => boolean) 
    constructor(isGreater?: (v1: T, v2: T) => boolean) {
        this.isGreater = isGreater ?? function (v1: number, v2: number): boolean {return v1 > v2};
//            ^ It gives an error, because @number are not equalent @T
    }
```

If change `number` to `T` you can get sistuation like that:

```
const inst = new Foo<string>() 
// No error, but compare function.. 
// ..by default works only with @numbers
```

I want user to have 2 possible ways to create an instance:

1. **No type annotation** - all defaluts, so you get `T` as `number` by default and default function to compare numbers
2. **Type annotation (T)** - you **have to** give function which satisfeis `(v1: T, v2: T): boolean`, except your type is `number`, so default function is OK

I tried to use condition:

```
...(v1: T extendes number ? number : T, v2 T extendes number ? number : T): boolean...
```

It didn't work. I tried to find a solution, but all of them lead to **create type of unions**, which can not be used here because of **class** (you cant use **type** on class properly), or create overloads on constructor, but it was for variables - at this case is a **type** depence.

Comment: Yeah, this is more or less the missing feature at [ms/TS#56315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56315). The closest I can get involves some ugly type juggling and at least one assertion, as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/mbrddm). Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining. If not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz, thank you so much! The solution are great! Not hard to understand, so everything is fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is a pain point of TypeScript. It's essentially a missing feature that you can't easily make a [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) function (or constructor) with a [default argument](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Default_parameters) that corresponds to a [default type argument](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults).  There's an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#56315](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/56315) (at least for functions), but for now it's not part of the language and you need to work around it.

The workaround for functions is easier than for generic class declarations because the generic type parameter for classes can't be changed on a per-construct-signature basis.  But we can mostly do it.  Here's one way:

For ease of discussion, let's define a `Cmp<T>` utility type for comparisons, and give a name to that default argument:

```
type Cmp<T> = (v1: T, v2: T) => boolean;
const g: Cmp<number> = function (v1, v2) { return v1 > v2 }
```

And now the class constructor looks like:

```
class Foo<T = number> {
    isGreater: Cmp<T>
    constructor(
        ...args: [T] extends [number] ? [isGreater?: Cmp<T>] : [isGreater: Cmp<T>]
    )
    constructor(isGreater: Cmp<T> = g as Cmp<T>) {
        this.isGreater = isGreater;
    }
}
```

So we only have a single [overloaded](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-overloads) construct signature, which uses a [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters) to let you either make the `isGreater` parameter [optional](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-0.html#optional-elements-in-tuple-types) or required depending on whether `T` is assignable to `number` (via a non-distributive [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html)).

Then, inside the implementation, we just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that `g`, the default `Cmp<number>` is a `Cmp<T>`.  The intent here is that the only way this could actually happen is if `T` is assignable to `number`, and therefore `Cmp<number>` is assignable to `Cmp<T>` (note the change of assignability direction due to *contravariance* of function inputs, see [Difference between Variance, Covariance, Contravariance, Bivariance and Invariance in TypeScript](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66410115/2887218) for more information).

Let's test it out:

```
const inst = new Foo() // okay
//    ^? const inst: Foo<number>
const inst2 = new Foo((x: string, y: string) => x.localeCompare(y) > 0);
//    ^? const inst: Foo<string>
const inst3 = new Foo(g);
//    ^? const inst: Foo<number>
const inst4 = new Foo<string>(); // error!
// ---------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Expected 1 arguments, but got 0.
```

Looks good. If you construct `new Foo()` with no argument you get a `Foo<number>`.  If you pass in an argument of type `Cmp<T>` for some `T`, then you get a `Foo<T>`. And if you try to specify the argument `T` manually as anything not assignable to `number`, the compiler will require that you pass in an argument for `isGreater` as well.

So that's fairly type safe from the construct caller's point of view.  From the class implementer's point of view, we've had to play some type juggling games and done assertions, so care needs to be taken.  But until and unless microsoft/TypeScript#56315 is implemented, this is probably the best we can do.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAwgtmAPAFQHxQLxQBQDcCMAXFMgDRS4BMxyAlJugEYD2zANhAIYB2A3AFABjZtwDOwKAHNi8JNwCucRhABO6LADN53QcACWInAXJV6AbygqIweSu4V8UdFSgBffkLadRoqADFWFEwoBSVVdDN+KGioPVEAcStOYFUZBBRUKJjhMWAVeV1mFWwAOjLOFUlRYgBtZABdKAgADxTuABNfGtDlFUaAfigauMSuFJV+tKQ0RtqRpPGpjPraLOic8XzC4vmx1Nh0tGDJKG8D6dRzNZjo4AALOJLd5NVg5-GBG-d3IRFxWNywW4EAA7v5WNhVgB6KE3AB6-V+gL0uUoQNB4OY2GwzWImxRknIIDxeQJ9Aw6GaJTYzEEnA4MGYCAqEGwIHo6AADLQBDD4YiNhIUeIAMzosEBLGSHn8PkxBFI-7C4AAFnFmMQ+O4klQkN4UD5qhURQAhPwgA)